# When you close application, keep the service running

Tags: android, service, notifications

So I have a service

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotifcationService.class);
startService(i);
```

But now I want it so when I close the app in the manager, it won't kill the service. I've looked into sticky service but that caused the service to stop working.

Also background, the server handles gathering information from a IRC.

Comment: Why don't include a loop in the service?

Comment: 2Trebia Project It´ll kill the battery